# load image in winforms using pack uri

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uri

I have a problem trying to show some images on my winform.
On one form, I have an wpf container, which has a WPF control that has no problem to load images from an external exe (that have the images as resources), which references the dll that contains the form, with the wpf container, that shows them.

Now, I want to add another winform, and I need to show there, the same images that are shown using the wpf container, but I cannot add a wpf container to this form, because I need to show the images on a combobox.

How can I load this images using URI pack, or how I turn this uri to something that I can use from my winform.

example uri.

```
pack://application:,,,/myPack;component/Images/image.png
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is read the image data for use in Winforms, so you need direct access to the embedded resource image file, which can be done thusly:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/myPack;component/Images/image.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetContentStream(uri);
System.Drawing.Image myImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(info.Stream);
```

Edit: If you get an exception about invalid port, make sure you've registered the pack scheme, which you can do merely by referencing it.  So put this line of code before the above:

```
string s = System.IO.Packaging.PackUriHelper.UriSchemePack;
```

Comment: I have tried this already and it gives me : Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.

Comment: which library I must import to use StreamResourceInfo and Application.GetContentStream ??

Comment: StreamResourceInfo: System.Windows.Resources. Application: System.Windows.  Can you accept the answer, please?

Comment: BTW, as long as you've added references, you can use Ctrl+. (control plus period) to auto-add the using statements to your code.

Comment: Just my two cents: both classes have been moved to the PresentationFramework library, so you will have to reference that, and Application.GetResourceStream(uri) should be used if it's a resource, otherwise it will return null.

Comment: +1 for the string s = System.IO.Packaging.PackUriHelper.UriSchemePack; It helped my problem with the invalid port. It would be nice to find out what was the actual problem and how come this fixes it.